# CSS transition and z-index conflict

Tags: css, z-index, css-transitions, transition

For a new webdesign I'm trying to control two 50% width layers with CSS transitions and z-index, but there seems te be a conflict: the z-index seems to be too slow. As you can see in the fiddle, the white box is hidden behind the right slider div on hover, until the transition is complete. Is there an alternative that works faster? Or is there another way to do it? Any help would be much appreciated!

This is my CSS:

```
body {
    background:black;
}
div {
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.6s ease, width 0.6s ease;
    transition:opacity 0.6s ease, width 0.6s ease;
}
.slide {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:50%;
    -webkit-transform:skew(-15deg);
    -moz-transform:skew(-15deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(-15deg);
    -o-transform:skew(-15deg);
    transform:skew(-15deg);
    z-index:2;
}
.slide:hover {
    width:60%;
    z-index:3;
}
.slide#left {
    left:0;
}
.slide#right {
    right:0;
}
.wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.inner {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transform:skew(15deg) scale(1.5);
    transform:skew(15deg) scale(1.5);
    opacity:0.5;
    position:absolute;
}
.inner:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
.inner#left {
    background:url(//savado.nl/new/key.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -ms-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
}
.inner#right {
    background:url(//savado.nl/new/code2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -ms-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
}
.slide .logo {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
    top:50%;
    height:20%;
    padding-left:20%;
    background:white;
}
.logo#left {
    right:0;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(50%) translateY(-50%) skew(15deg);
    -moz-transform:translateX(50%) translateY(-50%) skew(15deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(50%) translateY(-50%) skew(15deg);
    -o-transform:translateX(50%) translateY(-50%) skew(15deg);
    transform:translateX(50%) translateY(-50%) skew(15deg);
}
.logo#right {
    left:0;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) skew(15deg);
    -moz-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) skew(15deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) skew(15deg);
    -o-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) skew(15deg);
    transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) skew(15deg);
}
```

And here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dRe4/1/)!

PS: I'm new to posting questions of my own on this forum, so I'm sorry if I disobey any of the rules. Besides that, my English is not the best, since it's not my native language (I'm Dutch). But please help me out!

Comment: What does "slow z-index" mean?

Comment: If you check the fiddle, you can see that the z-index is too slow, because the white box on top of the right sliding part is hidden behind the box on hover.

Comment: thats because you are set width 0.6 sec, change it for 0.3 s if u want faster

Comment: I know what he means, I think. For some reason the logo, even though it has z-index 99 while the slide has 2 or 3 on hover, the logo is still behind on the z axis until the hover animation is completed which only occurs on the right slide, works well with the one on the left.

Comment: @Deathmras: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: @MatthewAbrman: That's exactly what I mean!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks Like the problem was only in Chrome but not in FF. What you need to do is set a smaller z-index on the wrapper container like this

```
.wrap {
  z-index:1;
}
```

That should fix it and here is the updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8dRe4/3/)

Comment: I suggest writing a new question :)

Comment: adding a z-index to the transition worked, this didnt.

Comment: Ok this seemed to have worked for me as well though probably @Kazim Hussain answers works as well. Now the question why is it doing this? Is there more documented question about this?

Answer (score 4):

Add z-index in your transition declaration. This should stop the z-index from executing before the transition

```
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.6s ease, width 0.6s ease,z-index 0.6s;
transition:opacity 0.6s ease, width 0.6s ease, z-index 0.6s;
```